# Are $k$-regular linear set systems vertex-transitive?

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

For any integer $k\geq 2$, a $k$-regular linear set system is a set ${\cal E}\subseteq {\cal P}(\omega)$ such that $|e| = k$ for all $e\in {\cal E}$, and moreover, for all $a\neq b\in\omega$ there is exactly one $e\in {\cal E}$ such that $\{a,b\}\subseteq e$. ([There is indeed](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428639/8628) a $k$-regular linear set system on $\omega$ for any given integer $k\geq 2$.)

We say that a set system ${\cal A}\subseteq {\cal P}(\omega)$ is *vertex-transitive* if for all $a, b\in \omega$ there is a bijection $\varphi:\omega\to\omega$ such that

1. $\varphi(a) = b$, and
2. for all $X\in{\cal A}$ we have $\varphi(X) \in {\cal A}$ as well as $\varphi^{-1}(X)\in {\cal A}$.

**Question.** If $k\geq 2$ is an integer and ${\cal E}\subseteq{\cal P}(\omega)$ is a $k$-regular linear system, is ${\cal E}$ necessarily vertex-transitive?

Comment: You seem to mean $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, not $e\subseteq\omega$? otherwise for $e\in\mathcal{E}$ you have $e\in\omega$ which makes $\{a,b\}\subseteq e$ senseless (unless you really consider integers as set of integers...).

Comment: By $k$-regular do you mean $k$-uniform, i.e., each edge is incident with $k$ vertices?

Comment: @YCor Sorry for getting my notation wrong - will correct! Indeed I meant ${\cal E} \subseteq {\cal P}(\omega)$ in the first line. At bof: I want to say that every $e \in {\cal E}$ contains exactly $k$ members of $\omega$

Comment: Do you know whether for some $k$ there exist more than one (up to isomorphism) $k$-regular linear set system? Do you know whether for every $k$ there is a vertex-transitive $k$-regular linear set system?

Comment: You have a good answer below. I’d wildly guess that there are many (perhaps in some sense almost all) examples with only the identity automorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Introduction**

I'll provide plenty of non-transitive examples (*just be patient, please*).

Let me introduce a useful and more general notion of *selector system* instead of *linear set system*; then, I will specialize it to the *linear* ones. even in the special case, we can equivalently consider an arbitrary infinite countable set in place of $\omega$.

**Remark** We will see that my complete (2 n)-systems are the same as the OP's linear set systems.

---

---

**Definition of the systems and extensions**

A selector system is an ordered triple  $\ (X\ \cal B\,\ \sigma)\ $ (*please, do not edit my comma-free notation*), where $\ X\ $ is an arbitrary set, $\ \cal B\subseteq 2^X,\ $ and $\ \sigma:B\to2^X\ $ satisfies two axioms:

$$ \forall_{B\in\cal B}\quad B\cap\sigma(B)\ =\ \emptyset $$
and
$$\forall_{A\ B\in\cal B}\quad(A\subseteq B\cup\sigma(B)\,\ \Rightarrow
       \,\ A\cup\sigma(A)\ =\ B\cup\sigma(B)) $$

Selector system $\ (Y\ \cal D\,\ \phi)\ $ extends selector system
$\ (X\ \cal B\,\ \sigma)\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow $ $ X\subseteq Y,
\ \cal B\subseteq\cal D,\ \sigma=\phi|\cal B,\ $ and

$$ \forall_{B\in \cal B}\,\forall_{D\in\ \cal D}
   \quad (D\subseteq B\cup\sigma(B)\,\ \Rightarrow\,\ B\cup\sigma(B)
     \ =\ D\cup\phi(D))  $$

---

---

(k n)-**systems and their *free style* purposeful extensions**

Let $\ 1<k<n\ $ be natural numbers. In this section, let selector system $\ (X\ \cal B\,\ \sigma)\ $ be such that
$\ \emptyset\ne\cal B\subseteq$ $\binom Xk,\ $
$\ |\sigma(B)|=n-k,\ $ and

$$ \binom{B\cup \sigma(B)}k\subseteq \cal B $$
for every $\ B\in\cal B.\ $ Then we can construct an extension
$\ (Y\ \cal D\,\ \phi)\ $ that is similar (as we will see soon), and that has also the following ***purposeful property***:
$$ \binom Xk\ \subseteq\ \cal D $$
**Let's do it:**

Let set $\ T\ $ has cardinality $\ |T|=n-k,\ $ and let $\ Y\ $ be the
following disjoint "$\cup$":

$$ Y\,\ :=\,\ X\ \cup\ \left(\binom Xk\setminus\cal B  \right)\times T, $$

and
$$ \cal D\ :=\ \cal B\,\cup
   \bigcup_{b\in\binom Xk\setminus\cal B}\binom{b\cup\phi(b)}k,$$

*(sometimes the MO software forces calligraphic $\ \cal X\ $ in place of simple $\ X$)*

where $\ \phi\ $ extends $\ \sigma\ $ as follows:

$$ \forall_{b\in\ \binom X2\setminus\cal B}\quad \phi(b)\ :=
         \ \{b\}\times T $$
and

$$ \forall_{b\in\ \binom Xk\setminus\cal B}\,
  \forall_{c\in\binom{b\cup\phi(b)}k}\quad\phi(c):=(b\cup\phi(b))\setminus c
 $$

Otherwise, $\ \phi(B)=\sigma(B)\ $ for $\ b\in\cal B.$

Thus, if $\ X\ $ is countable then so is $\ Y.$

The above extension was done in the ***free style***.

---

---

**Complete selector** (k n)-**systems**

Now, we get an entire class of infinite countable ***complete*** selector systems
$\ (X_\infty\ \cal B_\infty\ \sigma_\infty) $ such that
$\ B_\infty=\binom {X_\infty}k,\ $ and
$$ \forall_{b\in\binom {X_\infty}k} |\sigma_\infty(b)|=n-k  $$

***Remark**:   In general, the complete systems don't have to have the triple index $\infty$ in their names.*

We obtain a system as this as an extension of arbitrary countable system
$$ (X_0\ \cal B_0\ \sigma_0)\ :=\ (X\ \cal B\,\ \sigma), $$
where
$$ \binom Xk\setminus\cal B\ \ne\ \emptyset $$

Then we obtain $\ X_{s+1}\ \cal B_{s+1}\ \sigma_{s+1}\ $ from
$\ (X_s\ \cal B_s\ \sigma_s)\ $ the way we have obtained
$\ (Y\ \cal D\,\ \phi)\ $ from $\ (X\ \cal B\,\ \sigma)\ $ for every $\ s\in\mathbb N.$ Now we define:

$$ X_\infty\ :=\ \bigcup_{s=0}^\infty\, X_s\qquad\text{and}
 \qquad\cal B_\infty\ :=\ \bigcup_{s=0}^\infty\,\cal B_s,   $$
and let $\ \sigma_\infty\ $ be the common extension of all $\ \sigma_s,\ $
onto $\ \cal B_\infty.$

THe above complete extension was done in the ***complete free style***.

---

---

**No certain intermediate subsystems**

Let $\ (X_0\ \cal B_0\ \sigma_0)\ :=\ $ $(X\ \cal B\,\ \sigma)\ $ be an
(k n)-system, and let $\ (X_\infty\ \cal B_\infty\ \sigma_\infty)\ $ be
the complete extension of $\ (X\ \cal B\,\ \sigma)\ $ done in the complete
free style.

We also assume the non-completeness condition:
$$ \binom Xk\setminus\cal B\ne\emptyset $$

---

**Theorem**   There does not exists an intermediate **complete**
subsystems $\ (Y\ \cal D\,\ \phi\ ) $ such that
$$ \qquad 0\ <\ |Y\setminus X|\ <\ \infty\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (\#) $$

---

**Proof**

By (#), there exists $\ s\in\mathbb N\ $ such that
$$ Y\setminus X_s\ =\ \emptyset\ \ne\ Y\setminus X_{s-1} $$
Let $\ x\in Y\setminus X_{s-1}.\ $ Then, for arbitrary
$\ L\subseteq\binom{X_{s-1}}{k-1}\ne\emptyset\ $ and $\ p:=\{x\}\cup L\ $
we have
$$ \emptyset\ \ne\ \sigma_{s+1}(p)\ \subseteq\ X_{s+1}\setminus X_n $$
Thus, $\ p\notin\binom Yk.\quad$ **End of Proof**

---

---

**Non-transitive examples**

Let (k n)-system $\ (X_1\ \cal B_{-1}\ \sigma_1)\ $ be complete, i.e.
$$ B_{-1}\ =\ \binom{X_{-1}}k $$

The examples can be taken from finite geometries or trivial (finite or nor)
when $\ |X_{-1}|=n\ $ hence necessarily $\ \cal B_{-1}:=\binom{X_{-1}}k$.

Let $\ e\ $ and $\ X_0\ :=\ X_0\cup\{e\}\ $ be such that
$\ e\in X_0\setminus X_{-1}.$
Then we get an induce non-complete (k n)-system
$\ (X_0\ \cal B_0\ \sigma_0),\ $ where
$$ X_0:=X_{-1}\cup{e}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\cal B_0=\cal B_{-1}\qquad
 \text{and}\qquad\forall_{B\in\cal B_0}\ \sigma_0(B):=\sigma_{-1}(B) $$

---

**Theorem**   In every such situation as above, if $\ X_0|<\infty\ $
then

$\ (X_\infty\ \cal B_\infty\ \sigma_\infty)\ $ is an infinite complete
(k n)-system that is not vertex transitive.

---

**Proof**   Indeed, there is no authomorphism $\ X_\infty\to X_\infty $
can map any element of $\ X_{-1}\ $ to any element of
$\ X_\infty\setminus X_0.$     **End of Proof**

Comment: @bof, thank you for catching and correcting my English typo-like error.

Comment: Thanks Wlod AA for your long answer, as I have to run to a meeting, I have to wait for the afternoon / evening to fully digest it. Will get back later today on this!